# Django Login dont work, how i can i fix it?

Tags: django, authentication, web, private

I have a functional login feature on my website, but unfortunately, the private page can still be accessed by typing in its URL, even without logging in. I am concerned about this security flaw and would like to know how I can prevent users from accessing the private page without first logging in. Can you offer any advice or guidance on how to address this issue?

I asked ChatGPT for help. It suggested putting "login_required" before "def", but it's not working.

```
def login_view(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
username = request.POST['username']
password = request.POST['password']
        
user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
login(request, user)
return HttpResponseRedirect('/Händlerpage/
 else:
     return render(request, 'login.html', {'error_message': 'Ungültiger Login'})
 else:
 return render(request, 'login.html')



@login_required
def Händlerpage(request):
  return render(request,'Händlerpage.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your template, try using:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %} <div></div> {% endif %}
```

The `<div></div>` will be gone for every not-authenticated (= not-logged-in) User

---

You can remove the '@login_required' btw.

From personal experiences, using ChatGPT for Django wont work 90% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Pass login url if you want to use decorator like this:

```
@login_required(login_url="/login_view/")
def Händlerpage(request):
  return render(request,'Händlerpage.html')
```

This will prevent users to access this page if they're not logged in the system and they will get redirected to login page. Refer [Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator)

Another option you can define `LOGIN_URL` in `settings.py` then you can
use decorator without specifying url which you were trying earlier:

```
LOGIN_URL = "/login_view/"
```